# Bash on alpine linux

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I cannot get a bash shell into an alpine container.

I'm starting with this Alpine container:
`gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine`

I'm adding a bash shell and other configs in this dockerfile:

```
from gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine

ENV http_proxy=<corporate_proxy>
ENV https_proxy=<corporate_proxy>

RUN apk add vim wget curl nmap lsof bash bash-completion which

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
RUN ls -l /bin # THIS WORKS, I CAN SEE 'BASH' SHOW UP WITH 755 OWNED BY ROOT
RUN which bash # THIS ALSO WORKS
RUN /bin/bash -c "echo hi" # YES, THIS WORKS TOO
```

However when spawning the container to use a bash shell via:
`docker run -idt <image_name> /bin/bash`, the container fails to start with `FATAL: Command /bin/bash not found.`

Note that these other options also fail for me when spawning a container: `ash, sh, /bin/ash, /bin/sh, etc`

running the container with `--user root` also does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entrypoint is a GitLab Runner script. Change it to bash to get shell access:

```
$ docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash <image_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out something funky was being set in the container's entrypoint.  I need to remember to override the entrypoint when spawning a new container via `docker run`.

Adding this line in the Dockerfile fixed the problem:

```
ENTRYPOINT: []
```

Answer (score 0):

1- verify if you container in fully loaded by :

```
docker ps
```

so after to enter in bash shell like:

```
docker exec -it <<container_name>> bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Alpine doesn't have bash, use sh instead:

```
docker exec -it 64103333b32 /bin/sh
```